# 最高得点と最低得点を出したいのですが・・・

Tags: java

java内での入力

```
import java.io.*;
class sample61{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    System.out.println("テストの受験者数を入力してください。");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String str = br.readLine();
    int num = Integer.parseInt(str);

    int[] test;
    test = new int[num];
        int total = 0;
        int max = 0;
        int min = 100;
        int ave = 0;

    System.out.println("人数分の点数を入力してください。");
    for(int i=0; i<num; i++){
        str = br.readLine();
        int tmp = Integer.parseInt(str);
        test [i] = tmp;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<num; i++){
       System.out.println((i+1) + "番目の人の点数は" + test[i] + "です。");
          total = total + test[i];
    }
    System.out.println("合計点:" + total + "点");
    System.out.println("最高得点:" + max + "点");
    System.out.println("最低得点:" + min + "点");
    System.out.println("平均得点:" + total/num + "点");

  }
}
```

以上のプログラムを実行すると以下のようになります。
(入力を含む)

```
テストの受験者数を入力してください。
5
人数分の点数を入力してください。
90
79
1
55
78
1番目の人の点数は90です。
2番目の人の点数は79です。
3番目の人の点数は1です。
4番目の人の点数は55です。
5番目の人の点数は78です。
合計点:303点
最高得点:0点
最低得点:100点
平均得点:60点
```

結果の最高得点と最低得点を以下のように表示したいです。

```
最高得点:90点
最低得点:1点
```

しかし上記の実行例で示したように以下のようになってしまいます。

```
最高得点:0点
最低得点:100点
```

改善するところがあれば指摘してください。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: maxとminの計算が行われていません。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

変数 max と min を計算していないため、初期値が表示されていますね。

表示する前に計算しましょう。